# how to find smallest number satisfies having given number of solutions

Tags: equation-solving, number-theory

I want to find the smallest number $t$ which satisfies $t=a^2+b^2$ ,where there are 12 pairs of $a$ and $b$ solution.

my first code is very slow

```
Cases[Table[{t, 
Solve[{t == a^2 + b^2, a >= b > 0}, {a, b}, Integers] // 
Length}, {t, 100000, 200000}], {_, 12}]
```

---

after some search, I find this

```
NestWhile[# + 1 &, 100000, Length[PowersRepresentations[#, 2, 2]] <= 11 &]
```

and this

```
NestWhile[# + 1 &, 100000,  Length[IntegerPartitions[#, {2}, Range[1000]^2]] 
<= 11 &]
```

---

Someone tell me another way,get this

```
Cases[Tally@Flatten@Table[i^2 + j^2, {i, 1, 500}, {j, i, 500}], {_, 12}]
```

after using `Outer` ,get faster solution.

```
Cases[Tally[Flatten[Outer[Plus, #, #] &@(Range[500]^2)]], {_, 24}]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your searches are fast, but you may never know if they are complete. Here is a solution based on `Reduce` which guarantees you have found all cases.

The number of representations of $t=a^2+b^2$ with $a\ge b>0$ is $c=\frac{1}{2}(1+e_1)(1+e_2)...$, where the $e_i$ are exponents of primes $p\equiv1$, mod 4, in the prime factorisation of $n$. This expression requires even $c$, and for your question $c=12$.

Use `Reduce` to find up to 4 exponents $e_i$, exponentiate the smallest primes $p$ to find candidate $n$, and finally choose the smallest $n$ of the groups. Testing integers with 5 primes is not required because $2^5$ exceeds the required 24.

```
Block[{s1, s2, s3, s4, e1, e2, e3, e4, p, n1, n2, n3, n4},
   s1 = {e1} /. {ToRules[Reduce[{(1 + e1) == 24, e1 > 0}, {e1}, Integers]]};
   s2 = {e1,e2} /. {ToRules[
      Reduce[{(1 + e1) (1 + e2) == 24, e1 > 0, e2 > 0}, {e1, e2}, Integers]]};
   s3 = {e1, e2, e3} /. {ToRules[
      Reduce[{(1 + e1) (1 + e2) (1 + e3) == 24, e1 > 0, e2 > 0, e3 > 0},
             {e1, e2, e3}, Integers]]};
   s4 = {e1, e2, e3, e4} /. {ToRules[
      Reduce[{(1 + e1)(1 + e2)(1 + e3)(1 + e4) == 24, e1>0, e2>0, e3>0, e4>0},
             {e1, e2, e3, e4}, Integers]]};

   p = Pick[#, Mod[#, 4], 1] &[Prime[Range[20]]];

   n1 = Times @@@ Map[Take[p, 1]^# &, s1];
   n2 = Times @@@ Map[Take[p, 2]^# &, s2];
   n3 = Times @@@ Map[Take[p, 3]^# &, s3];
   n4 = Times @@@ Map[Take[p, 4]^# &, s4];
   Map[Min, {n1, n2, n3, n4}]
]
```

> {11920928955078125, 6865625, 359125, 160225}

The smallest number $t=a^2+b^2$ having 12 pairs of solutions is 160225, corresponding to exponents $\{2,1,1,1\}$ of primes $\{5,13,17,29\}$.

Comment: Please provide a reference for the formula in the second paragraph.  Thanks.

Comment: I do not have a web or book reference. Only a comment by user MuthuVeerappanR on a Project Euler Forum page. This page is inaccessible unless you have solved the problem.